# Flutter radio button custom to select single item

Tags: dart, flutter

code snippet is to maintain the state of each ListView item.
This code is for checkbox style, I am looking for single selection at time. I want to select only one item.looking for a solution.

The logic of radio button is needed. for example there is  a horizontal list of circles , when the user click on a single circle, it should get a border. when the user click on other circle, all other circle borders should remove the borders.

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new ListItemDemo(),
  ));
}

class ListItemDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("ListItem"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new MyListItem(
              title: "Hello ${index + 1}",
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MyListItem({this.title});

  @override
  _MyListItemState createState() => new _MyListItemState();
}

class _MyListItemState extends State<MyListItem> {
  bool isSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isSelected = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("${widget.title} ${isSelected ? "true" : "false"}"),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (isSelected) {
              setState(() {
                isSelected = false;
              });
            } else {
              setState(() {
                isSelected = true;
              });
            }
          },
          child: new Text("Select"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty solution: Just maintain let's say an array of boolean with each element referring to the state of each element(where it is selected or not) in the list. Of course, every selection, there should only be one "true" value in your array since you want to execute a radio-like logic.

I edited your code. Just check for errors since I didn't run this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new ListItemDemo(),
  ));
}

class ListItemDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  var arrayState = [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("ListItem"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new MyListItem(
              title: "Hello ${index + 1}",
              array: arrayState, 
              setter: changeArrayState,
              ind: index,
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  void changeArrayState(int index)
  {
      for(int i=0; i<arrayState.length; i++)
      {
          arrayState[i] = false;
      }

      arrayState[index] = true;
  }
}

class MyListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<bool> arrayState;
  final void Function(int) changeState;
  final int index;

  MyListItem({this.title, this.arrayState, this.changeState, this.index});

  @override
  _MyListItemState createState() => new _MyListItemState();
}

class _MyListItemState extends State<MyListItem> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text("${widget.title} ${widget.arrayState[widget.index] ? "true" : "false"}"),
        new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {

              setState(() {
                widget.changeArrayState(widget.index);
                //change the border the way you like
              });

          },
          child: new Text("Select"),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you help with code. I am not able to figure out